# SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#'

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm getting a Syntax error while trying to run a simple application. I'm trying to use the `Netbeast API` (https://github.com/netbeast/api) in my code, but I get the syntax error in the line I import netbeast

`var beast = require('netbeast')`

This is the error that is thrown:

(https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16781072/14606538/068a2322-057e-11e6-8f40-e69cb4a1710a.png)

It happens in **iOS and Android**, and I'm using **react-native 0.22** in Mac.

I think it is because react-native does not support yet one (or more) of the packages used by netbeast, but I don't know which is causing the error.

Any idea about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the source files started with `#!`, which is invalid JavaScript. Node strips the hashbang but React Native didn't.

This has been patched in React Native and is planned to go out with RN 0.26.